# Searching a string array for next available empty space then mark space as taken

Tags: java, arrays

I have a 2d string array for displaying a seating plan.

```
String seating[][] = {{"XX", "02", "03","04","XX","06","07","08","09"},
                     {"10", "11", "12","13","XX","15","16","17","18"},
                     {"19", "20", "21","22","23","24","25","26","27"}};
```

What I am looking to do is search though the array for an available space, not already marked by 'XX', and then assign 'XX' to that space to show it as taken.
I know you can use a nested for loop to search though the array and display element inside the array however, I am struggling to understand how I can insert a new element to mark the spot as taken. I am quite new to programming so any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: So is your expected output `"XX", "XX", 03"...`?

Comment: Once you find the location, just set the location to "XX". You're simply replacing the old value.

Comment: How would you assign a value to a 1d array? That's the same for 2d arrays, just add another index information (i.e. `seating[...][...]` instead of `seating[...]`).

Comment: @Sweeper Yes this is how I would expect the output, as I would want the program to occupy point for 0, 0 onward

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that you are not adding a value to the 2D array here, (arrays' lengths are fixed anyway) you are just setting the value of an element of the 2D array.

As you know, this is how you loop through a 2D array:

```
for (int i = 0 ; i < seating.length ; i++) {
    for (int j = 0 ; j < seating[i].length ; j++) {

    }
}
```

Inside the loop, `seating[i][j]` is the element that we are checking. We want to check if this is not occupied:

```
if (!seating[i][j].equals("XX"))
```

If it is not occupied, we set it to occupied:

```
seating[i][j] = "XX";
```

Don't forget to stop the loop after you found a seat with a `break;`! Since we want to break out of the outer loop, you need to mark the outer loop with a label.

Full code:

```
outer: for (int i = 0 ; i < seating.length ; i++) {
    for (int j = 0 ; j < seating[i].length ; j++) {
        if (!seating[i][j].equals("XX")) {
            seating[i][j] = "XX";
            break outer;
        }
    }
}
```

You could also add a boolean variable to check for whether a seat is successfully occupied:

```
boolean seatFound = false;
outer: for (int i = 0 ; i < seating.length ; i++) {
    for (int j = 0 ; j < seating[i].length ; j++) {
        if (!seating[i][j].equals("XX")) {
            seating[i][j] = "XX";
            seatFound = true;
            break outer;
        }
    }
}
if (seatFound) {
    // a seat was successfully occupied!
} else {
    // the seats were already all full!
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this was a good explanation and helped me understand what to do and how it worked and help to solve my problem. Thanks again.